# can not compile C++ constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Can anyone please explain to me whats wrong with this piece of code and how to fix it?
this is part of a bigger project if you need more information in order to give an anwer please let me know.

the error that im getting is this:

```
  g++ -c search.cpp
    search.cpp: In constructor ‘Search::Search()’:
    search.cpp:26:26: error: ‘callnumber’ was not declared in this scope
    make: *** [search.o] Error 1



Search::Search()
        {
            ifstream input;
            input.open("data.txt", ios::in);

            if(!input.good())
                //return 1;
            string callnumber;
            string title;
            string subject;
            string author;
            string description;
            string publisher;
            string city;
            string year;
            string series;
            string notes;

            while(! getline(input, callnumber, '|').eof())
            {   
                getline(input, title, '|');
                getline(input, subject, '|');
                getline(input, author, '|');
                getline(input, description, '|');
                getline(input, publisher, '|');
                getline(input, city, '|');
                getline(input, year, '|');
                getline(input, series, '|');
                getline(input, notes, '|');


            Book *book = new Book(callnumber, title, subject, author, description, publisher, city, year, series, notes);
            Add(book);
            }   

                input.close();

        }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It's hard to see mistakes like this if you've been staring at the code for too long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On this line:

```
if(!input.good())
    //return 1;
string callnumber;
```

You commented out the line with the semicolon and you're not using braces, and C++ is not white-space sensitive when it comes to spaces and newlines<sup>1</sup> between tokens, so by taking out the comment (and adding indentation) we can see that it's the equivalent of

```
if (!input.good())
    string callnumber;
```

And we can see that the declaration of `callnumber` is local to the `if`. Add braces or a semicolon to make the declaration of `callnumber` be outside the `if` (or just remove it completely):

```
if (!input.good()) { // or ;
    //return 1;
}
string callnumber;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Except in macros

Comment: @user1325414 **ALWAYS** use braces. It takes less than a second.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've commented this line

```
if(!input.good())
    //return 1;
```

The string callnumber is only declared inside that scope and unusable outside of it.

Remove the if statement too or uncomment the return line

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(!input.good())
            //return 1;
        string callnumber;
```

is effectively

```
        if(!input.good()) {
            //return 1;
            string callnumber;
        }
```

because the commented-out `//return 1;` isn't a statement.  So `callnumber` is created and then immediately vanishes out of scope.